# Setting CreationTime of a directory

Tags: c#, directory, fileinfo

I am trying to set the **creation time** of a **directory** with C#.

This works very easy with files in this way:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strFile);
fi.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
```

So I tried it with a path to a directory and got an object (so `FileInfo` worked on a directory) and it threw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when setting the time like in the code above.

I am working on Windows 7 64bit and have administrator-rights on.

**Question:** So, how can I set the creation time of a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it with this, haven't seen it yet....

```
Directory.SetCreationTime(strFile, DateTime.Now);
```